# if statement in render not considered

Tags: reactjs

I'm a little embarrassed because it's probably very easy. Unfortunately, I've been debugging the code for an hour and can't see the forest for the trees.

This is my functional component:

```
export function PrivateRoute({component: Component, ...rest}) {

return (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) => (
            rest.fixedParameter.user != null ? (
                <Component {...rest.parameter} />
            ) : (
                rest.fixedParameter.user === null ? (
                    <>
                        {doSomethingHere()}
                    </>
                ) : (
                    rest.fixedParameter.user === 1234 ? (
                            <>
                                {doSOmethingDifferentHere()}
                            </>
                        ) :
                        (
                            <>
                                Route is null
                            </>
                        )
                )
            )
        )
        }
    />
)
}
```

The problem now is that the code always goes into the component (`<Component {...rest.parameter} />`), regardless of whether user is null or not.

I have debugged it and the user is null. Nevertheless, the IF statement has no influence. I can also write `1 == 2 ?` there and the code always goes into the component.

Thank you

Comment: `rest.fixedParameter.user !== null`

Comment: Did you try the above suggestion?

Comment: Yes, sadly this is also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**//Solution**

The problem were the functions. React or Routes (I don't know) can't handle the situation if nothing is rendered.

The code works if there is an exit to each IF statement. Working example:

```
export function PrivateRoute({component: Component, ...rest}) {

return (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) => (
            rest.fixedParameter.user != null ? (
                <Component {...rest.parameter} />
            ) : (
                rest.fixedParameter.user === null ? (
                    <>
                        {doSomethingHere()}
                        Loading ... You have to output anything here
                    </>
                ) : (
                    rest.fixedParameter.user === 1234 ? (
                            <>
                                {doSOmethingDifferentHere()}
                                Loading ... You have to output anything here
                            </>
                        ) :
                        (
                            <>
                                Route is null
                            </>
                        )
                )
            )
        )
        }
    />
)
}
```